# .NET docker buster images for 6.0

Tags: dockerfile, .net-6.0

I need buster image for .NET 6.0

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build

What should be for .net6.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Buster images are images based on Debian 10 ([Buster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Sarge_and_later_releases_(2005%E2%80%93present))), there is no official images for .NET 6 based on Buster (see full tag listings for [SDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/) and [ASP.NET Core](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet)), only on Debian 11 (Bullseye), so you can take those (6.0-bullseye-slim).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this DockerFile in your Project

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
LABEL Remarks="gET SDK FOM MICROSOFT"
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YieldExample.dll"]
```

Answer (score -1):

To Run Your Container can use below commands in debian os

```
$ docker build .
$ docker images
$ docker run [imageName]
```